# Registry Alternative

Tags: windows, registry

I have a program that I sell.  I have some basic protections in place to keep people from just copying the program folder and running the program.  Right now I am storing keys, mainly used for tracking installation registration (which is tied into an encrypted license system).

So I actually WANT to store something in a semi-hard to find and edit location, that is global to the machine (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), not a specific user of that machine (I can't use the users folder).  All other application settings are stored either per user or per machine with either the exe or in the users folders, so it is just these two keys stored in the registry that I'd like to stop putting there.

Is there a way to do what I want without using the registry?

Not that it should matter but the code is .Net (one module is C# the other VB).

Comment: Be aware that writing to any machine-wide location, whether it's in the registry or not, requires being an administrator.

Comment: The usual convention is to generate some sort of key based on the MAC address of the machine's primary ethernet interface.  Such a key can be stored alongside the executable, or anywhere else convenient; if copied to another machine, it won't work.

Comment: Harry, I personally don't like tying things to hardware configs, since it doesn't allow you to change your hardware without breaking things.

Comment: The impact of a hardware association can be minimized by allowing automated reactivation, etc., to be honest I'd be more worried about the potential impact of having obscured licensing information.  System administrators don't like having mysterious stuff lying around, it is liable to be mistaken for something malicious and deleted.  Creating a directory in the common application data folder sounds like a reasonable choice, though, so long as you give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you don't realize, any roll-your own "copy protection" is not going to be very effective if your application becomes at all popular. You complicate life for legit. users in any case -- as well as your support issues. Copy protection is a bit of a misnomer, what you are really trying to accomplish is execute protection.

In terms of "obscure locations", the registry is a popular choice for a good reason. It is a very crufty place, that most users are loathe to visit, if they are even aware of its existence.

Check out the [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration constant for use with the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) function

The CommonApplicationData folder is not particularly well-known and it is at least a legit. area to store per-application data. This will resolve to different locations on disk depending upon your windows version.

ADDED

As I recall, no admin priv. is needed -- after all, it is an shared application data folder -- I've used it before without admin priv. but who knows what happens under Window 9, etc. Be sure to put it in a subfolder instead of the CommonApplicationData folder itself.

BTW, the registry also requires elevated priv. to write in modern versions of Windows (for most key locations). Your installer program should run with elevated priv. but your application should not. Some of the other special folders may also need elevated priv., don't know anyplace this is conveniently documentated.

Comment: Gary, I'm not too concerned about it becoming popular, since this is for a niche market with engineering emphasis.  I'm also not too worried about making it super secure.  The CommonApplicationData folder looks really promising and I will definitely check it out.  Do you know if it requires admin privileges to write to?

Comment: No, you don't need admin permission to create a new directory in the common application data folder.  However, depending on what you're going to be doing with the directory you may need to explicitly set permissions for it when you create it.

Comment: Gary, thanks for the info, this definitely sounds like a winner.  When I get a chance to change and play around I'll let you know how it goes.

@Harry - I really only need to write one (or two) files that just contain a single GUID each one time, then just read them from then on, so hopefully I won't need anything permission wise.  It has to be better than the registry at least, and then I can get away from requiring the program to be run as an admin.

Comment: Gary - I tried it out and it works like a charm, no more registry, no more run as admin.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You could create a kind of "encrypted" ini/xml-File in the exe-Folder.
This file can be created first time program starts (or when user registers), including info about installation and maschine.
(Copying a file anywhere in the filesystem is not good idea.)

**EDIT:**
as mentioned in the comments, it looks like it is not a good idea to use the programs-bin folder, it may require admin-rights to write in this folder.

So, it seems to be not easy to find a location (beside User-Folder and Win-Registry) which exists (permanently) an all Win-Computers and can be used to write files (without having admin rights).

Maybe you can use C:\Users\All Users (or C:\Users\Public (which i do not recommend)) ?

Comment: Writing to a machine-wide location, like the program directory, requires running at administrator level.  If the user is an administrator, then this is almost certainly pointless.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: in this context, I wouldn't imagine that to be a problem.  The data is probably only being written during installation.

Comment: Ben, that is what I'm doing essentially.  I am just using a GUID as part of the encryption key.  The GUID is attained at first run of program and stored in the registry.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:  The proposed answer specifically says "create [the] first time [the] program starts," which doesn't sound like it's being done by the installer.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: oh, I see what you mean.  The basic idea is sound, though, it just needs to be part of the installation rather than the first run.  (A disappointing number of programs make that same mistake.)